# Incremental Filter DataFrame using distinct values with Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

First of all I have a dataframe with distinct values:

```
| Days |
| day1 |
| day2 |
| day3 |
```

Then, I have another Dataframe with some values like this

```
| A | B | Days |
| 1 | 2 | day1 |
| 3 | 4 | day3 |
| 5 | 6 | day3 |
| 7 | 8 | day2 |
```

I want to filter the second dataframe with the values of the first. First I want to obtain one dataframe filtering day1, then day1 and day2 and finally day1, day2 and day3 (incremental).

The outputs would be:

```
| A | B | Days |
| 1 | 2 | day1 |

| A | B | Days |
| 1 | 2 | day1 |
| 7 | 8 | day2 |

| A | B | Days |
| 1 | 2 | day1 |
| 7 | 8 | day2 |
| 3 | 4 | day3 |
| 5 | 6 | day3 |
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

use the filter() function dataframe by combining with and() operator.

example

```
var days = df1.collectAsList
import spark.implicits._

val d1 = df2.filter($"Days".equalTo(days.get(0).getString(0)))
val d2 = df2.filter($"Days".equalTo(days.get(0).getString(0))
.and($"Days".equalTo(days.get(1).getString(0))))
val d3 = df2.filter($"Days".equalTo(days.get(0).getString(0))
.and($"Days".equalTo(days.get(1).getString(0)))
.and($"Days".equalTo(days.get(2).getString(0)))
)
```